# How to add or subtract milliseconds with calculated value or from a field?

Tags: postgresql, milliseconds

In **Postgresql**, I try to subtract 5 milliseconds
(using fixed constant, when I search on Google, most of example using fixed constants)

```
SELECT ([field start_date] - interval '00:00:00.005') AS work_timestamp
from mytable
```

How to change '5' or '00:00:00.005' form query above
with a calculated process or from a field value

with a field value (field ms_value) :

```
SELECT ([field start_date] - interval '00:00:00.00'+[field ms_value]) AS work_timestamp
from mytable
```

with a calculated process (field ms_value1 and ms_value2 or other calculated process) :

```
SELECT ([field start_date] - interval '00:00:00.00'+[field ms_value1-field ms_value2]) AS work_timestamp
from mytable
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid concat. Multiply by a constant of 1 millisecond seems better

```
select now(), now() - (5 * interval '1  ms')
```

if 5 is provided externally

```
select now(), now() - ($1 * interval '1  ms')
```

5 could potentially be (field ms_value1- field ms_value2) in your final example.

Comment: why avoid concat ?

Comment: Readability firstly (compared with  '00:00:00.00' || [field ms_value]), the intent above is clearer, the units are clear, although this can be argued is subjective. 

Secondly, whilst the original post doesn't declare their parameter types, the above is harder to shoot yourself in the footer as there is no implicit cast from text to integer, whilst nearly everything has an assignable or implicit cast to text. This can become important where you enforce your parameter validation, is this destined for a plpgsql statement? a prepared statement or some dynamic sql submitted from your app ?

Comment: Although, admittedly, I would perhaps edge towards make_interval if working at a precision of seconds as suggested by a_horse_with_no_name - I actually didnt know that existed - not sure how I feel about necessary division when scaling millisecond units upto seconds. hmm ymmv

Comment: I think I will choose this because easy to read, most simple syntax,  support unsupported/outdated PostgreSQL version, easy to change unit and unit position on the right side (like we write unit on everyday math). Thanks to other answers

Answer (score 0):

The solution I usual use is Concatenates the values with its unit, afterthat cast it to Interval.

i.e:

```
select now(), now() - ('5'|| ' ms')::interval
```

In your case will be

```
SELECT ([field start_date] - ('00:00:00.00' || [field ms_value])::interval AS work_timestamp
from mytable

SELECT ([field start_date] - ('00:00:00.00' || ([field ms_value1-field ms_value2]))::interval AS work_timestamp
from mytable

SELECT ([field start_date] - (([field ms_value1-field ms_value2]) || ' ms')::interval AS work_timestamp
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a quick calculation:

```
SELECT field - (INTERVAL ’1 millisecond’ * 5) FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use make_interval()

```
select start_date - make_interval(secs => ms_value/1000.0)

select start_date - make_interval(secs => (ms_value1-ms_value2)/1000.0)
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/vUa18rMx)

Comment: => got me error message, I changed to :=

Comment: @FZS then you are using an outdated and unsupported Postgres version.

Comment: I only get unwanted result when put directly integer value in the query, such as "select make_interval(secs => 5/1000)" 
After casting it into Numeric it is okay "select make_interval(secs => 5::numeric/1000)"

Comment: @MabuKloesen: see my answer. That's why I used `1000.0` not `1000`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name wow, such a good trick. I got it.